# Micronaut POJO deserialisation error message when the format is invalid or type throws error

Tags: deserialization, micronaut

When providing the incorrect format of a field for a request to my application if the type throws an error then the error message returned by micronaut is vague.

E.G two scenarios

```
public class fakeClass {
    @NotNull
    private String fakeName;
}
```

if my request is `{"fakeName": ""}`

then the response, correctly, would be something like

```
{
"violations": [
    {
        "field": "create.fakeClass.fakeName",
        "message": "must not be blank"
    }
],
"type": "https://zalando.github.io/problem/constraint-violation",
"title": "Constraint Violation",
"status": 400 }
```

But lets say my class looks like this:

```
   public class fakeClass {
    @Format("yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate exampeDate;
}
```

With an invalid date or incorrect format of `{"exampleDate": 202222--01-01}` or `{"exampleDate": 2022/01/01}`

Then the error message is

```
{
"type": "about:blank",
"parameters": {
    "path": "/project"
},
"status": 400,
"detail": "Required argument [fakeClass fakeClass] not specified"
```

}

Is there a simple way to provide more information to the error message to make it clear why the request failed for an invalid format or type like @NotNull or @NotBlank?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not Micronaut but your payloads. The examples you mentioned are **invalid JSON documents**.

For example this on here is invalid, since the value is not a number nor a string.

```json
{
  "exampleDate": 202222--01-01
}
```

this would be the a valid variant

```json
{
  "exampleDate": "202222--01-01"
}
```

Make sure you send the date as a String. In your case this is expected to be valid.

```json
{
  "exampleDate": "2022-11-01"
}
```

In general it is recommended to send date using the ISO-8601 format, which you did (yyyy-MM-dd). Furthermore I recommend to apply a global configuration rather than using on each POJO a `@Format("yyyy-MM-dd")` annotation.

```yaml
jackson:
  dateFormat: yyyyMMdd
  timeZone: UTC
  serializationInclusion: NON_NULL
  serialization:
    writeDatesAsTimestamps: false
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up re the global configuration. I'll try that. \n

My example requests are actually a mistake. They are, in fact, strings (albeit incorrectly exemplified above). 

E.G 
`{
  "exampleDate": "20222--01-01"
}
`

Gives the error:
`"detail": "Required argument [fakeClass fakeClass] not specified"`

rather than:
`{
        "field": "create.fakeClass.fakeName",
        "message": "must not be blank"
   }`

Answer (score 0):

`@Format("yyyy-MM-dd")` is a formatter not a [Constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html).

You can use `@Pattern(<regex>)`. There is also date specific ones like `@Past`, `@PastOrPresent`, `@Future`and `@FutureOrPresent`.